# How to create 1 group to sum 4 elements with xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I am trying to use muenchian to do a group/sum, but I can't make it work.
Any help available?! :) 
XML I have:

```
<RLA760910>
 <G_L_By_Object_Account___Localization_S10>
  <Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3>401100.900</Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3>
  <SumBegBalance>-20</SumBegBalance>
  <SumDebitPeriod>10</SumDebitPeriod>
  <SumCreditPeriod>-5</SumCreditPeriod>
  <SumEndBalance>-15</SumEndBalance>
 </G_L_By_Object_Account___Localization_S10>
 <G_L_By_Object_Account___Localization_S10>
  <Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3>401100.900</Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3>
  <SumBegBalance>100</SumBegBalance>
  <SumDebitPeriod>10</SumDebitPeriod>
  <SumCreditPeriod>-5</SumCreditPeriod>
  <SumEndBalance>105</SumEndBalance>
 </G_L_By_Object_Account___Localization_S10>
  <Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3>411100.900</Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3>
  <SumBegBalance>-30</SumBegBalance>
  <SumDebitPeriod>5</SumDebitPeriod>
  <SumCreditPeriod>-10</SumCreditPeriod>
  <SumEndBalance>-35</SumEndBalance>
 </G_L_By_Object_Account___Localization_S10>
  <Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3>451100.900</Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3>
  <SumBegBalance>80</SumBegBalance>
  <SumDebitPeriod>20</SumDebitPeriod>
  <SumCreditPeriod>-10</SumCreditPeriod>  
  <SumEndBalance>90</SumEndBalance>
 </G_L_By_Object_Account___Localization_S10>
</RLA760910>
```

I've so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  <xsl:key name="AcctSub"
           match="/RLA760910/G_L_By_Object_Account___Localization_S10"
           use="@Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3" />
   <xsl:template match="Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3">
    <result>
      <!-- Match the first acct element for a specific group -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/RLA760910/G_L_By_Object_Account___Localization_S10/[generate-id() = generate-id(key('AcctSub', @Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3)[1])]" />
    </result>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="/RLA760910/G_L_By_Object_Account___Localization_S10">
    <total type="{@Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3}">
     <!-- Sum all the elements from the @type group -->
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('AcctSub', @Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3)/@Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3)" />
    </total>
   </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected result will sum
SumBegBalance, SumDebitPeriod, SumCreditPeriod, SumEndBalance Group BY Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3

Comment: **1.** Your XML is not well-formed. **2.** Please show the expected output **as code**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="AcctSub"
    match="G_L_By_Object_Account___Localization_S10"
    use="Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3"/>

  <xsl:template match="RLA760910">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="*[generate-id()=generate-id(
        key('AcctSub', Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3)[1])]">
        <result>
          <xsl:variable name="Objects" select="key('AcctSub',
            Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3)"/>
          <Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3>
            <xsl:value-of select="Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3"/>
          </Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3>
          <SumBegBalance>
          <xsl:value-of select="sum($Objects/SumBegBalance)"/>
            </SumBegBalance>
          <SumDebitPeriod>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum($Objects/SumDebitPeriod)"/>
          </SumDebitPeriod>
          <SumCreditPeriod>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum($Objects/SumCreditPeriod)"/>
          </SumCreditPeriod>
          <SumEndBalance>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum($Objects/SumEndBalance)"/>
          </SumEndBalance>
        </result>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A few notes:

1. `Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3` is not an atribute but an element, so `@`
   is not needed.
2. As the name of the root tag I used the same name as in your input.
3. Each `result` output tag contains `Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3` tag
   (the grouping key) and sums of your 4 tags (within the group).

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="grp" match="G_L_By_Object_Account___Localization_S10" use="Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3" />

<xsl:template match="/RLA760910">
    <result>
        <xsl:for-each select="G_L_By_Object_Account___Localization_S10[generate-id() = generate-id(key('grp', Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3)[1])]" >
            <group type="{Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3}">
                <total-of-begbalance>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('grp', Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3)/SumBegBalance)"/>
                </total-of-begbalance>
                <!-- add more totals here-->
            </group>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

When this is applied to the following **well-formed** example input:

**XML**

```
<RLA760910>
    <G_L_By_Object_Account___Localization_S10>
        <Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3>401100.900</Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3>
        <SumBegBalance>-20</SumBegBalance>
        <SumDebitPeriod>10</SumDebitPeriod>
        <SumCreditPeriod>-5</SumCreditPeriod>
        <SumEndBalance>-15</SumEndBalance>
    </G_L_By_Object_Account___Localization_S10>
    <G_L_By_Object_Account___Localization_S10>
        <Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3>401100.900</Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3>
        <SumBegBalance>100</SumBegBalance>
        <SumDebitPeriod>10</SumDebitPeriod>
        <SumCreditPeriod>-5</SumCreditPeriod>
        <SumEndBalance>105</SumEndBalance>
    </G_L_By_Object_Account___Localization_S10>
    <G_L_By_Object_Account___Localization_S10>
        <Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3>411100.900</Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3>
        <SumBegBalance>-30</SumBegBalance>
        <SumDebitPeriod>5</SumDebitPeriod>
        <SumCreditPeriod>-10</SumCreditPeriod>
        <SumEndBalance>-35</SumEndBalance>
    </G_L_By_Object_Account___Localization_S10>
    <G_L_By_Object_Account___Localization_S10>
        <Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3>451100.900</Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3>
        <SumBegBalance>80</SumBegBalance>
        <SumDebitPeriod>20</SumDebitPeriod>
        <SumCreditPeriod>-10</SumCreditPeriod>  
        <SumEndBalance>90</SumEndBalance>
     </G_L_By_Object_Account___Localization_S10>
</RLA760910>
```

the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result>
  <group type="401100.900">
    <total-of-begbalance>80</total-of-begbalance>
  </group>
  <group type="411100.900">
    <total-of-begbalance>-30</total-of-begbalance>
  </group>
  <group type="451100.900">
    <total-of-begbalance>80</total-of-begbalance>
  </group>
</result>
```

---

Note that your expressions using `@Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3` fail because `Zsz_ObjectAcctSub_OSBOW_ID3` is an element, not an attribute.